# Exception persisting a master-detail model with Primefaces and JPA

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, master-detail

I'm experimenting some strange log messages from netbeans when I try to persist a master detail form, even if I try to do the persistence writing the data from object on a java class.

My application have many entity classes, such as:

1. projects
2. providers
3. categories
4. subcategories
5. items
6. orders(master)
7. details(detail)

And other many that is unnecessary to mention. The deal is how am I trying to persist this objects within a prime faces form.

My orders entity (The Master) looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_orden_compra")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "OrdenCompra.findAll", query = "SELECT o FROM OrdenCompra o"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "OrdenCompra.findByIdOrdenCompra", query = "SELECT o FROM OrdenCompra o WHERE o.idOrdenCompra = :idOrdenCompra"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "OrdenCompra.findByNumeroOrden", query = "SELECT o FROM OrdenCompra o WHERE o.numeroOrden = :numeroOrden"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "OrdenCompra.findByFechaOrden", query = "SELECT o FROM OrdenCompra o WHERE o.fechaOrden = :fechaOrden"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "OrdenCompra.findByFechaRecepcion", query = "SELECT o FROM OrdenCompra o WHERE o.fechaRecepcion = :fechaRecepcion"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "OrdenCompra.findByLugarEntrega", query = "SELECT o FROM OrdenCompra o WHERE o.lugarEntrega = :lugarEntrega"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "OrdenCompra.findByNumFactura", query = "SELECT o FROM OrdenCompra o WHERE o.numFactura = :numFactura"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "OrdenCompra.findByGranTotal", query = "SELECT o FROM OrdenCompra o WHERE o.granTotal = :granTotal")})
public class OrdenCompra implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @TableGenerator(name = "orden_sec",
            table = "tbl_sequence",
            pkColumnName = "SEQ_NAME",
            valueColumnName = "SEQ_COUNT",
            pkColumnValue = "orden_sec"
    )
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "orden_sec")
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id_orden_compra")
    private Long idOrdenCompra;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 5)
    @Column(name = "numero_orden")
    private String numeroOrden;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "fecha_orden")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date fechaOrden;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "fecha_recepcion")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date fechaRecepcion;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 80)
    @Column(name = "lugar_entrega")
    private String lugarEntrega;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 25)
    @Column(name = "num_factura")
    private String numFactura;
    // @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "gran_total")
    private BigDecimal granTotal;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idOrdenCompra")
    private List<DetalleOrdenCompra> detalleOrdenCompraList;
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_proyecto", referencedColumnName = "id_proyecto")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Proyecto idProyecto;
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_provee", referencedColumnName = "id_provee")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Proveedores idProvee;

    public OrdenCompra() {
    }

    public OrdenCompra(Long idOrdenCompra) {
        this.idOrdenCompra = idOrdenCompra;
    }

    public OrdenCompra(Long idOrdenCompra, String numeroOrden, Date fechaOrden, Date fechaRecepcion, String lugarEntrega, String numFactura, BigDecimal granTotal) {
        this.idOrdenCompra = idOrdenCompra;
        this.numeroOrden = numeroOrden;
        this.fechaOrden = fechaOrden;
        this.fechaRecepcion = fechaRecepcion;
        this.lugarEntrega = lugarEntrega;
        this.numFactura = numFactura;
        this.granTotal = granTotal;
    }

    //Getters And Setters
}
```

Detail entity (The Detail) looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_detalle_orden_compra")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "DetalleOrdenCompra.findAll", query = "SELECT d FROM DetalleOrdenCompra d"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "DetalleOrdenCompra.findByIdDetalleCompra", query = "SELECT d FROM DetalleOrdenCompra d WHERE d.idDetalleCompra = :idDetalleCompra"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "DetalleOrdenCompra.findByCantidadItem", query = "SELECT d FROM DetalleOrdenCompra d WHERE d.cantidadItem = :cantidadItem"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "DetalleOrdenCompra.findByTotalItem", query = "SELECT d FROM DetalleOrdenCompra d WHERE d.totalItem = :totalItem"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "DetalleOrdenCompra.findByPrecio", query = "SELECT d FROM DetalleOrdenCompra d WHERE d.precio = :precio")})
public class DetalleOrdenCompra implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @TableGenerator(name = "detcomp_sec",
            table = "tbl_sequence",
            pkColumnName = "SEQ_NAME",
            valueColumnName = "SEQ_COUNT",
            pkColumnValue = "detcomp_sec"
    )
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "detcomp_sec")
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id_detalle_compra")
    private Long idDetalleCompra;
    // @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "cantidad_item")
    private BigDecimal cantidadItem;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "total_item")
    private BigDecimal totalItem;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "precio")
    private BigDecimal precio;
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_orden_compra", referencedColumnName = "id_orden_compra")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private OrdenCompra idOrdenCompra;
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_item", referencedColumnName = "id_item")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Items idItem;

    public DetalleOrdenCompra() {
    }

    public DetalleOrdenCompra(Long idDetalleCompra) {
        this.idDetalleCompra = idDetalleCompra;
    }

    public DetalleOrdenCompra(Long idDetalleCompra, BigDecimal cantidadItem, BigDecimal totalItem, BigDecimal precio) {
        this.idDetalleCompra = idDetalleCompra;
        this.cantidadItem = cantidadItem;
        this.totalItem = totalItem;
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

In the managedbean I have this implementation:

```
@ManagedBean(name="insumos_Controller")
@SessionScoped
public class Insumos_Controller {
    @EJB
    private OrdenCompraFacade ordenCompraFacade;
    @EJB
    private CalculoTotalItem calculoTotalItem;
    @EJB
    private ItemsFacade itemsFacade;
    @EJB
    private SubcategoriaFacade subcategoriaFacade;
    @EJB
    private CategoriasFacade categoriasFacade;
    @EJB
    private ProveedoresFacade proveedoresFacade;
    @EJB
    private ProyectoFacade proyectoFacade;

    //Decalaraciond e Variables
    private Proyecto selectedProyecto = new Proyecto();
    private Proveedores selectedProveedor = new Proveedores();
    private Categorias selectedCategoria = new Categorias();
    private Subcategoria selectedSubcategoria = new Subcategoria();
    private Items selectedMaterial = new Items();
    private OrdenCompra objOrdComp = new OrdenCompra();
    private DetalleOrdenCompra ojbDetOrdComp = new DetalleOrdenCompra();

    //Declaracion de Listas
    private List<Proyecto> listaProyectos = new ArrayList<Proyecto>();
    private List<Proveedores> listaProveedores = new ArrayList<Proveedores>();
    private List<Categorias> listaCategorias = new ArrayList<Categorias>();
    private List<Subcategoria> listaSubcategorias = new ArrayList<Subcategoria>();
    private List<Items> listaMateriales = new ArrayList<Items>();
    private List<DetalleOrdenCompra> dets = new ArrayList<DetalleOrdenCompra>();
    private DataModel<DetalleOrdenCompra> listaDetalle;

    //Contructor vacio
    public Insumos_Controller() {
    }

    //Metodos de programacion

    //Método que crea una lista de tipo Subcategorias filtrado por Categorias
    public String loadListaSubcategoxCatego() {

        List<Subcategoria> listaSubCategorias = new ArrayList<Subcategoria>();
        listaSubCategorias = subcategoriaFacade.consultarSubcatByCat(selectedCategoria);
        this.listaSubcategorias = listaSubCategorias;
        return "";
    }
    //Metodo que crea una lista detipo Material por Subcategorias
    public String loadListaItemsxSubcatego() {

        List<Items> listaItems = new ArrayList<Items>();
        listaItems = itemsFacade.consultarItemsBySubcat(selectedSubcategoria);
        this.listaMateriales = listaItems;
        return "";
    }

    //Metodo que agrega una linea a la lista de detalle de orden compra

    public String addDetalle() {

      //DetalleOrdenCompra det = new DetalleOrdenCompra(item.getIdDetalleCompra(),cantidadItem,totalItem,precio);
      dets.add(ojbDetOrdComp);
      //snuevoDetalle();

      //tsotalItem = calculoTotalItem.calculoTotalItem(det);

      return "";
    }

    public String deleteDetalle(DetalleOrdenCompra detalle) {
      dets.remove(detalle);     
      return "";
    }
    public BigDecimal getTotalITem() {
        BigDecimal totalItems = new BigDecimal("0.00");
        for(DetalleOrdenCompra d : dets) {
            totalItems = calculoTotalItem.calculoTotalItem(d);
            //ojbDetOrdComp.setTotalItem(calculoTotalItem.calculoTotalItem(d));

        }
        return totalItems;
    }

    //Getters y Setters


    public String nuevoDetalle(){
        ojbDetOrdComp = new DetalleOrdenCompra();
        //dt = new DetalleOrdenCompra();
        //dt.setDetalleMovimientoPK(new DetalleMovimientoPK());
        return "";
    }

     public String guardarCompra(){
        try {



            objOrdComp.setIdProyecto(selectedProyecto);
            // selected value from selectonemenu that display the list of providers
            objOrdComp.setIdProvee(selectedProveedor);
            // dets is the name of my arraylist type detail entity asigning the populated listin the form
            objOrdComp.setDetalleOrdenCompraList(dets);
            // at this point the master entity is filled (or setted)with all the needed onjects in its
            ordenCompraFacade.create(objOrdComp);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


         return"";

    }
}
```

So the implementation is very simple, obviously maybe I'm using some wrong implementation to persist, but in other form I have used that logic... and it worked fine.

When I click on the save button glassfish log shows this:

```
Advertencia:   A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB OrdenCompraFacade, method: public void com.comprasinventariopruebas.ejbs.AbstractFacade.create(java.lang.Object)
Advertencia:   javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:748)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:698)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:503)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4566)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2074)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2044)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy486.create(Unknown Source)
    at com.comprasinventariopruebas.ejbs.__EJB31_Generated__OrdenCompraFacade__Intf____Bean__.create(Unknown Source)
    at com.comprasinventariopruebas.controladores.Insumos_Controller.guardarCompra(Insumos_Controller.java:265)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    ... 50 more
```

Comment: please try to create a way more minimalistic example. But more importantly, the error comes from your code if I see it correctly. This is not PrimeFaces related I think

Comment: thank you for answer, yes the error marks the spot  ordenCompraFacade.create(objOrdComp); where you try to persist with the facade. about the code, there is no way to set more minimalistic the post because i already compressed it

Comment: as you can see there are 3 classes: master(OrdenCompra), the detail(DetalleOrdenCompra) and finally my managedbean(Insumos_Controller) there's no big deal for the post

Comment: I've simplified the post code implementation as  Kukeltje suggested me... I'm still waiting for the answer, because i still can't understand why the persist doesn't work...... thank in advance.